# Find a pattern and insert # at the beginning of 2 line before that and 1 line after that

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

I have a big file (more than 2000 lines). Where I have to insert a # at the beginning of 2 above lines and at the beginning of 1 below line after finding a pattern. Also insert # at the beginning of line where pattern found. Environment is Red Hat Linux. Also if you can explain, that would be great.

Take an example, please see below texts, Search "Fail" and # 2 lines before that and 1 line after that string (beginning of line). Also # line containing string "Fail".

```
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Fail
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Fail
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `perl`:

```
perl -p0e 's/(.*\n)(.*\n)(.*Fail\n)/#\1#\2#\3#/g' file
```

Here is how it works:

- `-p`: print program in the loop over all input lines
- `-0`: assume null as record separator
- `-e`: execute program from the command line
- `s/x/y/g`: substitute y for x anywhere in the file
- `()`: group together regular expressions
- `.*`: any character except newline repeated zero or more times
- `\n`: newline
- `\1`,`\2`,`\3`: access pattern from nth group `()`

Output:

```
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
#Name
#Number
#Reason = Fail
#Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
#Name
#Number
#Reason = Fail
#Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` solution using a sliding window (so there are never more than four lines in the pattern space at a time):

```
sed '1{N;N;};$!N;/.*\n.*\n.*Fail.*\n.*/{s/^/#/;s/\n/&#/g;};P;D' infile
```

On first line it reads in the `N`ext two lines (so now there are three lines in the pattern space).
Then, for each input line (including the first one) it pulls in the `N`ext line (so now there are four lines in the pattern space). If the third line in the pattern space matches `Fail`, it prepends each line in the pattern space with a `#`. Then, regardless, it `P`rints up to the first `\n`ewline and then `D`eletes up to the first `\n`ewline, restarting the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*Fail[^\n]*)\n/\n#\1\n#\2\n#\3\n#/g' file
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
#Name
#Number
#Reason = Fail
#Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
#Name
#Number
#Reason = Fail
#Reasult
Name
Number
Reason = Pass
Reasult
```

#### How it works

- `H;1h;$!d;x`

  These commands read the whole file in.
- `s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*Fail[^\n]*)\n/\n#\1\n#\2\n#\3\n#/g`

  This looks for four consecutive lines with `Fail` in the third line.  If that is found, then `#` are placed after each newline character.

  In more detail, a substitute command looks like `s/old/new` where `old` is a regular expression.  In our case, it is `\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*Fail[^\n]*)\n`.  Let's break that into its four parts:

  1. `\n([^\n]*)` finds the first line and saves it in group 1.
  2. `\n([^\n]*)` finds the second line and saves it in group 2.
  3. `\n([^\n]*Fail[^\n]*)` finds the third line but only matches if this line contains the word `Fail`.
  4. `\n` matches the fourth newline.  (The text of the fourth line is not saved: we don't need it.)

  If four lines match the above, then we replace them with `\n#\1\n#\2\n#\3\n#` which is the same as the input except that `#` are added after each newline character, `\n`.

  #### Mac OSX (BSD)

The above was tested on GNU sed. If using BSD sed, try:

```
sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*Fail[^\n]*)\n/\n#\1\n#\2\n#\3\n#/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a 4-line "window" in Perl:

```
perl -ne '
    push @w, $_;
    if (4 == @w) {
        if ($w[2] =~ /Fail/) {
            s/^/#/ for @w;
        }
        print @w;
        @w = ();
    }
' < input-file > output-file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line.
- `@w` is the window, it accumulates lines until there are 4 of them. At that moment, the third one is matched against `/Fail/`, and if present, each line in the window is prefixed with a `#`. Then, the window is printed and emptied.

Note: Might not print the last lines of the input if the last block is shorter than 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: Using `ed`, the interactive line-editor, to solve the problem:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/= Fail$/-2;+3 s/^/#/' 'w' 'q' | ed -s text.in
```

The editing script

```
g/= Fail$/-2;+3 s/^/#/
w
q
```

first applies the substitution `s/^/#/` (inserts `#` at the start of lines) to the lines from two lines above each match of `/= Fail$/` and three further lines down from there, in the whole file.

The `w` writes the changed buffer back to the original file, and `q` quits the editor.

Answer (score 0):

More simplyfied variant of [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225566/89144) 's script

```
sed ':a;/\(.*\n\)\{2\}/{P;D};N;/= Fail$/! ba;N;s/^/# /gm'
```